# What does the word 「へそのごみ」mean?

Tags: words, manga

It is a dialogue said by a boy who watched and criticized a theater play.　I also translated it myself for checking if I correctly understand the context.

わるいけどお先にしっけいするぜ。 --> It is not good but I have to say goodbye.

こんな茶番劇見てるなら　-->  If I have to watch this foolish play...

反省房へとじこもって**へそのごみ**でもとってたほうがよっぽどましだよ --> I think secluding myself in repentance room and doing/taking..... would be much better.

I'm not sure if it means doing/taking unimportant thing.

Comment: 「へそのごみ」よりは（同じ意味の）「へそのゴマ」という表現のほうがより一般的だと思います．（「へそのごみ」がありえないだろう，というほどの違和感は感じませんが）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it simply, he is saying that spending his time cleaning up his bellybutton would be a much more productive use of his time than watching that lame show.

- へそのごみ = bellybutton trash
- とってた = to pick
- ほうがよっぽどましだよ = is the much better thing to do.

He doesn't mean that he really wants to clean his bellybutton, it's just his way to insult the show.

わるいけどお先にしっけいするぜ。

> Sorry but I'm getting out of here.

Literally: sorry but I'm gonna be rude first.
It is a very casual way to say 「先に失礼します」and basically just mean that you are leaving first(which I suppose is seen as rude by Japanese standards.)
わるい can be used to say sorry.(and not "this is bad".)